# I can't connect to VPN under Ubuntu, what is possible on Windows

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, cisco, vpnc

I was provided with an access to the VPN server. All I got were server's IP, username and password. Under Windows connecting to the server was easy - I just had to type the information I received.

Problems started when I wanted to connect to the server from Ubuntu (14.04). I tried with `pptp` using many manuals from the web but nothing worked. Then `openvpn` - it requested a certificate I didn't have.

I asked server's admin if he can give me a bit more information about configuration and he told me

> *The VPN is set on a Cisco 2911 router*

I downloaded `vpnc` but it requires me to provide a group name and a group password but I don't have those. I'm in dark now.

Does someone know what should I do in order to connect to this server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of ubuntu, are you using?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: sorry form my late reply, u have cisco credentials, right?

Answer (score 0):

Install network-manager-openconnect by command:
**sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect.**

Now click on network menu, edit connections,and you can add a Cisco anyconnect VPN. Just enter the gateway and save it. 
Click on your vpn connection by going into network menu and then Enter your cisco credentials and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do you mean saying 'cisco credentials'? I have nothing more than an information I provided. 

I followed your instruction but when I click my newly created VPN connection, I get a window where there is no place to type user/password.

There's a 'VPN' Combobox at the top with a laverage icon to the right. Then there's a checkbox saying 'Automatically connect...', a field with  'Select a host to fetch the login from' text, 'Save passwords' checkbox and two buttons - 'Cancel' and 'Login' - both of them are grayed out. At the bottom theres 'Log' list.

Comment: After clicking the leverage icon I receive the following log: POST https:// ip_addr_here Attempting to connect to server ip_addr_here:443 | Failed to connect to host ip_addr_here | Failed to open HTTPS connection to ip_addr_here | GET https:// ip_addr_here Attempting to connect to server ip_addr_here:443 | Failed to connect to host ip_addr_here | Failed to open HTTPS connection to ip_addr_here ###### 'ip_addr_here' is a Gateway IP

Comment: see this article..  https://uci.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0010201

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the addition of a dedicated IP. It took a few weeks of back and forth with the VPN tech team, ultimately it was an issue on their end. make sure to ask very specific questions when you contact your VPN, and ask about what logs they need to see from you.

Answer (score 0):

Were you were using the AnyConnect application to connect on Windows? If so, then you will the need AnyConnect client for Linux.  Your server admin will need to provide the installer.  Once you have the installer, [here are the steps to configure it](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/routers/cisco-rv-series-small-business-routers/kmgmt-2597-Installing-AnyConnect-Linux-Ubuntu-desktop-User-Interface.html).